# How to post json to api method in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, django, json, rest, backbone.js

i have rest api based on django rest framework, that include next method of creation object, that takes the data in JSON-format on `'myapp/create_obj/'` and if the data is correct object will created, otherwise it returns an error also in JSON-format.

```
def create_obj(request):
    stream = StringIO(request.raw_post_data)
    data = JSONParser().parse(stream)
    serializer = ObjSerializer(data=data, many=True)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JSONResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
    else:
        return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Also i tried to create a module on backbone.js, that post the input in form data to this method. Im very new to js, in particular to backbone and i bad understand how backbone works with server api. i have something like

```
App.module('Createobj', function(Mod, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {

Mod.id = 'create-obj';
Mod.controllers = {};

Mod.Obj = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
      real_ref : '',
      share : ''
    }
  });

Mod.View = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
      id: 'create-obj-page',
      template: '#tpl-create-obj-page',
      model: Mod.obj,

      ui: {
          'real_ref': 'input[name=real_ref]',
          'share': 'input[name=share]',
          'error': 'div.error'
      },

      hammerEvents: {
          'tap button': 'submit:tap'
      },

      hammerOptions: {
          tap: true
      },

      showError: function(message) {
          this.ui.error
              .text(message)
              .show();
      },

      hideError: function() {
          this.ui.error.hide();
      },
});

Mod.Controller = SRClient.PageController.extend({
  id: Mod.id + '.main',
  ViewClass: Mod.View,

  setup: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.view, 'submit:tap', this.submit);
  },

  submit: function() {
    var real_ref = this.view.ui.real_ref.val(),
        share = this.view.ui.share.val();

    if (!real_ref || !share) {
        this.view.showError($t('create-obj.error_empty_fields'));
        return;
      }

    App.vent.trigger('loading-screen:show', $t('app.please_wait'));

    var obj = new Mod.obj({
        real_ref : this.view.ui.real_ref.val(),
        share : this.view.ui.share.val()
      });

  }});

Mod.addInitializer(function() {
  Mod.Controllers = {
    default: Mod.Controller
  };
  App.pageControllers[Mod.id] = Mod;
});
});
```

What i need to do, that data which i input in webform sends to `'myapp/create_obj'` in json-format? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone expects a RESTful api so instead of being the endpoint an action like create_obj, REST works with Resources and with HTTP methods. In your case you could have a Model like this:

```
var Obj = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
     real_ref : '',
     share : ''
   }
});
```

and a collection like this

```
var Objects = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   url: 'myapp/obj',
   model: Obj
});
```

the collection has a propetry `url` that specifies the server endpoint. So the operations will be

- POST /myapp/obj/ for create a new item
- GET /myapp/obj/:id/ if you want to retreive an specific item
- GET /myapp/obj/ retreving the whole list
- PUT /myapp/obj/:id/ update an item
- DELETE /myapp/obj/:id/ delete an item

[Tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a good framework to create RESTful api with Django.